# How did this trig equation got solved?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

How do you transform the first one into the second one ?
Could it be that it is incorrect ?

Comment: Have you had any thoughts? Do you know the formula for $\sin (A + B)$?

Comment: This is an inequation, not an equation.

Comment: no, please elaborate

Comment: $\frac 12=\cos \frac {\pi}{3}$; $\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}=\sin \frac {\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the double angle identity $\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)$
then remember that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}{}}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(x)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(x)=\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(x)+\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align}
&\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x \\
&\frac{1}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\\
&\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align}
Substitute and recall the addition formula for the sine.